# torch.cuda.is_available() retuns FALSE after installing appropriate versions of CUDA and CuDNN on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pytorch, ubuntu-20.04

[image]

I should say installations on Z490 motherboard with Ubuntu 20.04 are quite tricky.

[image]

Above are the screenshots from `nvidia --version` and `nvidia-smi`

I was able to complete all CUDA and CuDNN installations.

I used all of these. But GPU is not detected with pytorch.

```
pip3 install torch==1.5.1+cu101 torchvision==0.6.1+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

pip install torch torchvision

pip install torch==1.6.0+cu101 torchvision==0.7.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

A very huge thanks in advance. Someone please help me get out of this.

```
whereis cuda
cuda: /usr/lib/cuda /usr/include/cuda.h

whereis nvcc
nvcc: /usr/bin/nvcc /etc/nvcc.profile /usr/share/man/man1/nvcc.1.gz
```

But in some forums i have seen in some forums the path is /usr/local/cuda

In addition to that, my `~/.bashrc` contains these:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/cuda/include:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Pytorch doesn't use the system's cuda toolkit at all. When installed from pip or conda it comes with its own copy of the cuda library. The system drivers are the only thing that need to be up to date. Any issues with cuda not being available after updating the drivers is the result of installing the wrong pytorch package (either ones that were not compiled with any cuda support or not compiled with a version of cuda compatible with your system). Use the install commands from quickstart at [pytorch.org](http://pytorch.org) and select a version of cuda which is supported by your drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need `cudatoolkit`.

Installing from `conda` is the easiest:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

Or with cuda 10.1

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.

```
 $ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C03sv00001043sd000085ABbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Initially, while installing the nvidia drivers `nvidia-driver-450`wasnt available. But CUDA 11 toolkit is built on `nvidia-driver-450`. For that we need to install Nvidia Beta drivers using PPA repository.

using,

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450
```

The remaining process is the same. Install CUDA and CUDA toolkit, CuDNN and bammmm, there you go.
[image]